# Why can I connect to my container using rails server -b 0.0.0.0, but not with rails server command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

I have brand new `rails new testapp` app.

I create Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
CMD ["rails", "server"]
```

When I build and run it with `docker run -dp 3000:3000 testapp` I get `This site can’t be reached` when trying accessing `http://localhost:3000`.

When I change `CMD` to `["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]` it works fine.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Are you using Docker for Mac? Given rail's default to localhost (127.0.0.1), I would assume it is binding it to the docker host’s 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @agermain no, I'm on Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: As @agermain pointed out rails uses the local loopback `127.0.0.1` by default which is not the same as `0.0.0.0`. `127.0.0.1` is just as it sounds, a loopback, meaning that the loop is internalized on the hosting machine `127.0.0.1` is not accessible outside of the running machine and does not actually need any network interface at all. `0.0.0.0` on the other hand is configured to point at the default routing on most machines. [See this Post](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0) for more information